Generating a Dynamic DataFrame from an Existing Dataset
My goal is to create a DataFrame with unique name as Col A and a sumif of the original DataFrame from type, and the current iloc of the new DataFrame.
example of what my output should be
I tried to stay away from loops, but kept getting an error (error below the code)
def exercise_custom(df):
    cust_df = pd.DataFrame(df.nameDest.dropna().unique(), columns=['DestName'])
    cust_df['Payment_Count'] = len(df[(df['type']=='PAYMENT') & (df['nameDest']==cust_df.DestName)])
    display(cust_df.head(5))

return cust_df
pass     

The Traceback gives me
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[72], line 56
     52     return "TODO"
     54     pass
---> 56 visual_custom(df)

Cell In[72], line 40, in visual_custom(df)
     38 def visual_custom(df):
---> 40     exercise_custom(df)
     43     fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(6,10))
     44     #updated to show bottom labels correctly & chg color

Cell In[72], line 6, in exercise_custom(df)
      1 def exercise_custom(df):
      2     #X
      3     #for index, row in df:
      4         #cust_df = df['nameDest'].unique()
      5     cust_df = pd.DataFrame(df.nameDest.dropna().unique(), columns=['DestName'])
----> 6     cust_df['Payment_Count'] = len(df[(df['type']=='PAYMENT') & (df['nameDest']==cust_df.DestName)])
      7     display(cust_df.head(5))
     13         #X= pd.DataFrame(df['nameDest'].unique())
     14         #df[df_payment_count] = len(df[(df['type']=='PAYMENT') & (df['isFraud']==1)])
     15     
   (...)
     32              #              'Cash In':len(df[(df['type']=='CASH_IN') & (df['isFraud']==1)])}
     33             #    }

File ~/anaconda3/envs/forageenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py:76, in _unpack_zerodim_and_defer.<locals>.new_method(self, other)
     72             return NotImplemented
     74 other = item_from_zerodim(other)
---> 76 return method(self, other)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/forageenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py:40, in OpsMixin.__eq__(self, other)
     38 @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__eq__")
     39 def __eq__(self, other):
---> 40     return self._cmp_method(other, operator.eq)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/forageenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:6105, in Series._cmp_method(self, other, op)
   6102 res_name = ops.get_op_result_name(self, other)
   6104 if isinstance(other, Series) and not self._indexed_same(other):
-> 6105     raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")
   6107 lvalues = self._values
   6108 rvalues = extract_array(other, extract_numpy=True, extract_range=True)

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

One way I thought about fixing this is by looping, but its so slow and this needs to be quicker. (this was my last option cause all I was able to find was 'Loops are bad').
def exercise_custom(df):
    payment_counts=[]
    cust_df = pd.DataFrame(df.nameDest.dropna().unique(), columns=['DestName'])
    for name in cust_df['DestName']:
        filtered_df = df[(df['type'] == 'PAYMENT') & (df['nameDest'] == name)].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
        if len(filtered_df) == 0:
            payment_count =0
        else:
            payment_count=len(filtered_df)
        payment_count=len(filtered_df)
        payment_counts.append(payment_count)
    cust_df['Payment_Count'] = payment_counts
    display(cust_df.head(5))
    
    
    pass


Does groupby help? Something like df.groupby(['Dest_name', 'Type'], dropna=True).count() might give a hierarchical index. See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby

Please no picture, as recommended in [ask]. For dataframes, post the output of print(df) instead.

Please provide minimal reproducible examples of a dataset. What you want to do is possible, but I will need the data you're using. The answer should lie somewhere in .pivot() method

@Niqua I am not sure if I can share this data.. I'll dig in .pivot() and see if I can figure it out tho!

@PaulWilson - I did try that, but did not come out like I wanted. I'll revisit it with some clear eyes.

@OCa - Not sure if I could post the data. When I made a table to mimic the data; it got all messy looking

Then consider copy-pasting the output of print(df.to_dict()) -the ultimate dataframe sharing tool. (or use df.head() if too large)

Consider posting actual [mre]/ Help us help you :) Typically copy-pasting posting the output print(df) works well.

@PaulWilson - I figured a why to do it, but it was using groupby. Since you said that I needed to revisit that function; Can you post an answer so I can mark it correct?

Thanks @EricKidder, I'm glad you found it useful. I appreciate you wanting to pass on credit. However, I'm happy for you to post your solution (and upvote my original comment). If you've found the community contributions helpful, please also post a minimally reproducible example so others who find this post can benefit too--@OCa has provided a great example.

We can't reproduce your partial code because input data is not posted as text, but in a picture, and with inconsistent variables names (image shows "old"/"new" df but your code makes no reference to it). Nevertheless this is what can be said:
(1) What causes the error you report
First you define cust_df as a subset of df
cust_df = pd.DataFrame(df.nameDest.dropna().unique(), columns=['DestName'])

Then you require a member-by-member comparison of a column in cust_df and a column in df
df['nameDest']==cust_df.DestName

In the line above, both series must have the same lenth but they don't because cust_df is shorter than df by construction.
For further help, please share data as text and with consistent variables names. Your image shows "old"/"new" df but your code makes no reference to it.

(2) Suggested solution
With input:
df_old = pd.DataFrame({'Type' : ['Payment', 'Debt','Payment', 'Payment', 
                                 'Payment', 'Debt', 'Debt','Payment'],
                       'nameDest' : ['A']*4 + ['B']*4,
                       'Column A' : ['----']*8,
                       'Column B' : ['----']*8})
print(df_old)
      Type nameDest Column A Column B
0  Payment        A     ----     ----
1     Debt        A     ----     ----
2  Payment        A     ----     ----
3  Payment        A     ----     ----
4  Payment        B     ----     ----
5     Debt        B     ----     ----
6     Debt        B     ----     ----
7  Payment        B     ----     ----

A pivot_table one-liner does it nicely:
df_new = pd.pivot_table(data    = df_old,
                        index   = 'nameDest', # set the new index as the unique values found in column 'nameDest'
                        columns = 'Type',     # set the columns as the unique values found in 'Type'
                        values  = 'Column A', # Use any other column for count
                        aggfunc = len)        # aggregate as the length of each group
print(df_new)

Type      Debt  Payment
nameDest               
A            1        3
B            2        2

You have your frame now if you require a flat table, it's just a matter of cleaning up or resetting the indexes:
df_new.columns.name = None       # Remove mention of "Type" as name of index of columns 
df_new.reset_index(inplace=True) # Reset index of the rows 
print(df_new)

  nameDest  Debt  Payment
0        A     1        3
1        B     2        2

pivot_table is groupby made easy. It should be preferred to groupby wet work whenever possible.
Check this out:

A previous similar example: Groupby and Pivot Pandas table
A related project of canonical post: How can I pivot a dataframe?


Not sure if I can provide the data even if it is parse of the data, but I solved it. Granted, it is not like what I wanted, but this works for what I was trying to do

Could you explain why this is not like what you wanted- it looks exactly like your sample output, and does not usefor loops?
